# XDomainRequest on IE9 Access Denied

Tags: ajax, json

When going through my work network the following code works on IE9 and Cross domain json call. When trying the same code via my 3G modem I get an Error Access is Denied. It works in chrome and firefox thou. Only IE9 giving Access is Denied.
Please assist...

```
    if (!jQuery.support.cors && window.XDomainRequest) {
        //alert("in cors");
    var httpRegEx = /^http?:\/\//i;
    var getOrPostRegEx = /^get|post$/i;
    var sameSchemeRegEx = new RegExp('^'+location.protocol, 'i');
    var xmlRegEx = /\/xml/i;

    // ajaxTransport exists in jQuery 1.5+
    jQuery.ajaxTransport('text html xml json', function(options, jqXHR){
        // XDomainRequests must be: asynchronous, GET or POST methods, HTTP or HTTPS protocol, and same scheme as calling page        
        if (params.crossDomain && params.async && getOrPostRegEx.test(params.type) && httpRegEx.test(options.url) && sameSchemeRegEx.test(options.url)) {
            var xdr = null;
            var userType = (options.dataType||'').toLowerCase();
            return {
                send: function(headers, complete){
                    xdr = new XDomainRequest();

                    if (/^\d+$/.test(options.timeout)) {
                        xdr.timeout = options.timeout;
                    }
                    xdr.ontimeout = function(){
                        complete(500, 'timeout');                        
                    };
                    xdr.onload = function(){                        
                        alert("OnLoad");
                        var allResponseHeaders = 'Content-Length: ' + xdr.responseText.length + '\r\nContent-Type: ' + xdr.contentType;
                        var status = {
                            code: 200,
                            message: 'success'
                        };
                        var responses = {
                            text: xdr.responseText
                        };

                                try {
                                    if (userType === 'json') {
                                        try {
                                            responses.json = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {                                            
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            //throw 'Invalid JSON: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                    } else if ((userType === 'xml') || ((userType !== 'text') && xmlRegEx.test(xdr.contentType))) {
                                        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                        doc.async = false;
                                        try {
                                            doc.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {
                                            doc = undefined;
                                        }
                                        if (!doc || !doc.documentElement || doc.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length) {                                           
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            throw 'Invalid XML: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                        responses.xml = doc;
                                    }
                                } catch(parseMessage) {
                                    throw parseMessage;
                                } finally {
                                    //alert(status.code);
                                    complete(status.code, status.message, responses, allResponseHeaders);
                                }
                            };
                            xdr.onerror = function(){                               
                                complete(500, 'error', {
                                    text: xdr.responseText
                                });
                            };
                            xdr.open(params.type, params.url);                            
                            //xdr.send(options.data);
                            xdr.send();
                            //params.success(result, textStatus, jqXHR);

                        },
                        abort: function(){
                            if (xdr) {
                                xdr.abort();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
    };

jQuery.support.cors = true;

    //****************//
    $.ajax({ 
            url: params.url,
            type: params.type,
            dataType: params.dataType, 
            //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            async: params.async, 
            cache:params.cache, 
            data:params.data, 
            success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){
                result=result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\\)/gm,"");
                //console.log(result);
                params.success(result, textStatus, jqXHR);              
            },
            contentType:params.contentType, 
            error: function(xhrSend, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if(times>0){                    
                    makeRequest(times,params);
                }else{
                    //alert(params.url+params.data);
                    //alert(xhrSend);
                    //alert(textStatus);
                    //alert(errorThrown);
                    params.error(xhrSend, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }           
            }       
    });
```